QGIS Processing Tools - IDW Grid not recognising point file
I'm trying to convert my point (PointZ) layer into a grid using the Processing algorithm, Grid (IDW with Nearest Neighbor Searching, but whenever I run the algorithm, I get the error:
ERROR 4: `file:///C:/DTMs%20test/points.xyz?type=csv&delimiter=%20%5Ct&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&xField=2556076.68000802&yField=9985083.9999928&zField=-3715.99999088542&crs=EPSG:32075&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.
Process returned error code 1

The file definitely exists in this location in the system, and I even used the "..." to select the file. This seems to be happening with every file I try it on too. It also happens if I select the point layer as a layer, after inserting it in QGIS. When looking at the layer properties, it's a PointZ layer, which surely should work?

Export it to a format that's not delimited text, such as geopackage, shapefile, geojson or similar.

Have you tried with a directory that does not have space in the path? Like DTMs_test instead of DTMs test.

I made a test from directories "\data\space test" and from "\data". Both failed when I selected the layer from the QGIS layer list, and both succeeded, when I selected the file with a file selector. However with CSV it gets complicated to make the algorithm to recognize x, y, and z correctly. I recommend also convertin the CSV data first into some proper GIS vector format.
